# In postgresl, how to delete data efficiently when other tables point at that table that don't have an index on the foreign key?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

So say I have a table `condition`, and I want to delete everything in there by some other id.
That id lookup itself is indexed, so finding which records to delete from `condition` is easy.

However, now there are other tables, say `event` which has a foreign key to `condition`. And going over this entire `event` table with millions of records to confirm that there are no `condition_id` foreign keys pointing to the `condition` table is very slow. I've confirmed with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` that this costs the vast majority of time for this delete, over 1 hour.

Now of course I could add another index to this `event` table, but the table is big as it is.
And I have already deleted everything relevant from the `event` table beforehand, so I am 99% sure there aren't any foreign key violations in the first place. 99% sure because our Transaction Isolation Level is only `READ_COMMITTED` so there may be new entries afterwards that could point at `condition`.

Is there any way to speed up this delete in a SAFE way? I don't want to avoid any triggers, I do like the database integrity. I'm ok with this action failing if there are violations, but not that the database becomes corrupted. But these are rare actions and to add an entire index just for this purpose, which will slow down other inserts, sounds a bit overkill.

If the answer is just 'well that's just how it is, you need an index and suck up the downsides' then that's good to know too.

Edit: this is a slightly different example but shows the same problem. One of the `fk_subject` foreign key constraints, the one in a huge table where that id isn't indexed, makes this delete very slow:

```
"Delete on subject s  (cost=189.13..984.50 rows=0 width=0) (actual time=32.881..32.882 rows=0 loops=1)"
"  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on subject s  (cost=189.13..984.50 rows=16109 width=6) (actual time=0.765..3.972 rows=16118 loops=1)"
"        Recheck Cond: (project_id = '21fa9780-eb95-4fb0-8fd7-f0b513152539'::uuid)"
"        Heap Blocks: exact=528"
"        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on subject_project_idx  (cost=0.00..185.11 rows=16109 width=0) (actual time=0.665..0.665 rows=16118 loops=1)"
"              Index Cond: (project_id = '21fa9780-eb95-4fb0-8fd7-f0b513152539'::uuid)"
"Planning Time: 0.143 ms"
"Trigger for constraint fk_parent: time=48367.272 calls=16118"
"Trigger for constraint fk_subject: time=4839440.585 calls=16118"
"Trigger for constraint fk_subject: time=3705.218 calls=16118"
"Trigger for constraint fk_subject: time=2883.789 calls=16118"
"Trigger for constraint fk_subject: time=802.611 calls=16118"
"Trigger for constraint fk_subject: time=187.748 calls=16118"
"Trigger for constraint fk_subject: time=131.324 calls=16118"
"Execution Time: 4895610.450 ms"
```

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with the integrity (as long as we're not using really unsafe operations/hacks) but just with the possibility that that other table might still have references to the table being deleted. But normally there would be 0 records pointing at the records that are to be deleted. And no we don't do any manual lookups, those rows are just deleted as part of the bigger delete that this is part of. But the table still needs to be looked through (unindexed) for the db to make sure of that.

Comment: It's a rare user-action, but still a user-action, I don't want to go and make DDL commands part of our operation. DEFERRABLE would just delay the delay if I understand correctly.

Comment: If the delete only happens rarely, don't create the indexes and accept the long duration. Otherwise, create the indexes. There is no third option.